# How to test buy something in the webshop?

Tags: product, checkout

Hope all is well. 
I'm trying to configure my Google Analytics goals at the moment, but to no avail so far. One of the goals I - clearly - would like to define is when a client has bought something.

In order to get to know what my webshop redirects to after a client places an order, I'd like to test-buy an item and walk through the complete process - without having to pay the actual amount. Is there any convenient way to do this?

Many thanks in advance,

AWXX

Answer (score 1):

You can enable `Check / Money Order` payment method and use that to test placing order.

Comment: The above answer is what you want. If you are unsure of the location for Check / Money Order you need to log into the admin section of your website. Then using the navigation system -> Configuration. From this page on the left hand navigation select Payment Methods and you will see the option for Check / Money order. Ensure its set to enabled you will be able to purchase an Item and at the payment methods section select this new option so you dont have to make a "live" payment.